# ownCloud и LDAP из  AD

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap

Приветствую, админы.

Имеется у нас пара серверов. Один - контролер домена, второй - IIS.На первом сервере есть шара с нашими файлами. На всех папках и файлах соят права доступа для групп из AD. Т.е. без пользователя на шару не зайти.

Понадобился нам локальный сервер синхронизации, что-то по типу облака как dropbox. Выбор остановился на ownCloud. Поставил сперва на IIS, но нормальной работы добиться не получилось.

Затем установка этого добра благополучно заработала на nginx. LDAP модуль на IIS корректно не работал, на nginx еще не проверял. Поэтому возник вопрос, если на nginx все же заработает LDAP будет ли в таком случае сервер ownCloud обращаться к шаре с правами авторизованного пользователя или ему необходимы особые права на доступ к файлам и папкам?

Насколько вообще это безопасное решение для синхронизации файлов через интернет (другого удовлетворяющего нашим условиям пока найти не удалось)?

Answer (score 1):

Скорей всего ему потребуются отдельные права на все папки к которым у него будет доступ. Возможно, что от пользователя IIS_User*.

В случае с Linux (Ubuntu) ownCloud работает с файлами и папками с помощью юзера www-data и ему нужны соответствующие права.